# Django model save override without super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django. From this model generating a list and add. Now I have to override save action to not saving to DB but making a request to rest api, is local service. After success request new record is created in the database and it's accessible from Django.
I override save method in the model like this:

```
def save( self, *args, **kw ):
    // my http request
```

On the end, I don't call `super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`. Post request is created correctly, but I don't know how to make that the form behave in this same way like when normal save is used. Now save action hanging up and after a while I'm receiving http error 502

What should I call on the end of this method, or what I should return from it?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you only want to save the form inputs if an API request has been successful? And you don't want to use `super(Model, self).save()` to save it?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I oo not want to save it in this model at all. this API request saving this but this model still reading from database. Is not a right flow but right now I have to create fallback like this.

Comment: Ok, in this case you can just override the `save` method to return nothing (just use `return`)